# IntelliJ IDEA change import auto complete suggestion order

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellisense, static-import

Is there a way to change the order of autocomplete suggestions in IntelliJ. I think the autocomplete suggestions for methods and such are based on history, but if possible I'd like to reorder the following so static import is always the first option when it's available instead of the default *Create method*.

For example if I write the following assertion `assertThat(user.getAge(), is(123));` using Hamcrest Matchers and press `<alt> & <enter>` I get the following dialog. Is it possible to change the order of suggestions?

[image]